# the fonts and size of a tree displayed by ggtree

Tags: r, ggtree

I'm trying to use R package ggtree to visualize my polygenic tree. I use the following codes:

```
library(ggtree)
library(treeio)
tree_text<-read.table("tree.nwk")
tree <-read.tree(text=as.character(tree_text$V1))
ggtree(tree, layout="daylight") + geom_tiplab(aes(angle=angle))
```

Some tip labels of the tree are out of the plot region and invisible. I use the dev.size("in") command to get the size of the graphic window, and it returns: [1] 5.760417 5.750000. I wish the tree can be displayed in a A4 paper size region, so I try to make a larger graphic window by:

```
windows(height=8,width=8)
ggtree(tree, layout="daylight") + geom_tiplab(aes(angle=angle))
```

but it deoesn't work. The dev.size("in") command still returns: [1] 5.760417 5.750000, and some tip labels of the tree are still out of the plot region. If I use ggsave to save the image:

```
p<-ggtree(tree, layout="daylight") + geom_tiplab(aes(angle=angle))    
ggsave("tree.eps",p,height=8,width=8)
```

it gives an error:

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
      family 'sans' not included in postscript() device
```

If I save the image as pdf file:

```
postscript("tree.pdf",family="Times",fonts="sans")
```

it works and the image can be saved, but some tip labels of the tree are still out of the plot region. I try to increase the height and width value in ggsave, but the size of tree increases with the plot canvas, so invisible tip labels are always invisible

Do you know how to correct the problem and display all the complete tip labels of the tree? I will be grateful to any help！

Comment: I am not familiar with `ggtree`. but in case it is based on `ggplot2`, try adding `+ xlim(0, 6) + ylim(0,6)`?

Answer (score 0):

So I went and installed `ggtree`.

The following code are taken from the package [vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ggtree/inst/doc/treeImport.html).

```
library(ggtree)
raxml_file <- system.file("extdata/RAxML", "RAxML_bipartitionsBranchLabels.H3", package="treeio")
raxml <- read.raxml(raxml_file)
p <- ggtree(raxml) + geom_label(aes(label=bootstrap, fill=bootstrap)) + geom_tiplab() +
  scale_fill_continuous(low='darkgreen', high='red') + theme_tree2(legend.position='right')
p
```

[image]

Adding `xlim(0, 0.25) + ylim(0, 70)` shows most of the clipped texts.

```
p + xlim(0, 0.25) + ylim(0, 70)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, adding xlim and ylim can zoom the image and make it possible to show all the tip labels. However, because of the limited plot region, the tip labels may overlap with each other so that they can not be distinguished. So do you know how to produce a larger plot region so that the tip label overlapping may be overcome? I use windows(length,width),dev.new(length,width) to generate new plot regions to plot the tree, but the new regions are always 5.8 inches. I don't know why. Could you have a check on this?